# Teensy 4.1 serial communication with 7N2 (7 databits no parity 2 stopbits)

Tags: serial, teensy

I have ported a project from arduino Due to a teensy 4.1

In the project I read data from a sensor which speaks serial at 7 databits, no parity and 2 stopbits (no configurable).

Now it seems that [teensy does not support this dataformat](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_uart.html).
Could I read my sensor in a way using teensy 4.1? I could maybe use softwareserial but the format does not seem to be configurable.

Comment: maybe try to use `SERIAL_7N1 | SERIAL_2STOP_BITS`, I don't see why it shouldn't support it

Comment: Hi @KIIV I tried but it doesn't compile: 'SERIAL_7N1' was not declared in this scope. 7 databits with no parity is not listed in the supported dataformats.

Comment: Weird, how about  8N1 with masking that last bit to logic 1, so it'll look like 2 stop bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between 7N2 and 8N1. You just have the most significant bit of your data value being the first of the two stop bits.

To transmit just set the most significant bit to 1.

To receive just ignore the most significant bit.

For example:

```cpp
Serial.write(val | 0x80);
```

And:

```cpp
uint8_t val = Serial.read() & 0x7F;
```